# app-engine and python. how to go to subpath

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know `users.create_logout('example')` can direct to users to the path under the current path. like `/main/example/`, but what if i want to direct the users to the subpath of the example, say `/main/example/example1`, how do I do that? Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs say:

> **create_logout_url(dest_url)**
>   Returns
>   a URL that, when visited, signs the
>   user out, then redirects the user back
>   to the URL given as dest_url. This URL
>   is suitable for links, buttons and
>   redirects. dest_url can be full URL or
>   a path relative to your application's
>   domain.

...so you can put any full or relative path in as the argument, like:

```
 users.create_logout_url('/home/example/example1')
```

The URL is just a string, so you can do something like this (after your additional comment below):

```
currentUser = users.get_current_user()
logoutUrl = users.create_logout_url("/home/example/%s" % currentUser.nickname())
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying me first, but i forgot to detail my question like that I want my subpath to be /main/example/john or /main/example/joe or something like that, the subpaths can be changed according to the user accounts after they log in. Thank you

Comment: Thank you!!! that helps! btw, what i did was users.create_logout_url("/home/example/" + currentUser.nickname())
is that the same thing?

Comment: Should create exctly the same string, yes.

Comment: btw, after i direct the users to their pages, like /example/john, how do i make the webapp.requesthandler to handle the this page? if I do this ('/user.*',UsersSubPath) that matches the all pages after/user/, If I do ('/user/user.name*',UsersSubPath), thats not working either since it cant substitute the user.name by the user's name automatically. Thank you again

Comment: You should accept this answer, and create a new question for that part.